# unsigned int and double conversion order

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I'm confused by unsigned int and double conversion order. I thought that when evaluating an expression, the intermediate type is the one with the biggest cardinality of the representing set, but here in the code

```
unsigned int a1 = 4294967290, a2 = 4294967100;
unsigned int value1 = (a2 - a1) * double(0.1);
std::cout << value1 << std::endl;
unsigned int value2 = int(a2 - a1)* double(0.1);
std::cout << value2 << std::endl;
```

When compiling with Microsoft compiler, I receive these results:

value1 = 429496710
value2 = 4294967277

Whereas I thought that the immediate type of the answer should be double and therefore values1 and values2 should be equal

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 1: In the following, `(a2-a1)` has the `unsigned` value of `4294967100 - 4294967290 mod 4294967296` or `4294967106`.
   2: It is modded by `4294967296` because on your platform, `UINT_MAX` is `4294967295`.
   3: `4294967106 * 0.1` --> `(double) 429496710.6`
   4: Assigning `(double) 429496710.6` to `value1` results in a `(unsigned) 429496710`.

   ```
   unsigned int value1 = (a2 - a1) * double(0.1);
   ```
2. 1: With the below, it is more complicated.  `a2-a1` has the `unsigned` value of `4294967106`.  This value is cast to `int()` and results in unspecified/undefined behavior as @Yakk suggested.  A typical result is type `4294967106 - 4294967296` or `-190`.
   2: `-190 * 0.1` --> `(double) -19.0`
   3: Assigning `(double) -19.0` to `value2` is a problem as it is a negative number for an `unsigned`, again UB is encountered.
   4: `value2` was assigned the value of `(unsigned) 4294967277` which is the same bit pattern as `(int) -19` on your platform.

   ```
   unsigned int value2 = int(a2 - a1)* double(0.1);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You subtract two `unsigned int`.  This does arithmetic mod `2^k` for some `k` (probably 32).

In one case you convert this to `int`.  If it is greater than max int, the result is unspecified at least (and may be undefined behaviour: I forget).  This is probably the case here.  In practice this will generate a negative number on many systems, but trusting that is often a bad idea.

Then the `int` or `unsigned` is converted to a `double` arithmetically, multiplied by `0.1`, and then converted to an `unsigned int` arithmatically mod `2^k` for the same `k` (with possibly strange rounding going on: towards zero prior to conversion to unsigned?).

There is little reason to think these will result in the same value.